# AddDay and AddMonth function doesn't work, only AddYear on Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

So, I am making a program that will give new date based on how much time span given by user (like Date calculation in built-in calculator app in Windows 10/11). The problem is, I can only manage to add years, while the day and month stay the same.

Here's my attempt to do that:

```
Dim dateresult As String
Dim datenow As Date = Now.ToShortDateString
dateresult = datenow.AddDays(CBbDay.Text)
dateresult = datenow.AddMonths(CBbMonth.Text)
dateresult = datenow.AddYears(CBbYear.Text)
Label17.Text = dateresult
```

For example, if today's date is 1 January 2024 and the value of CBbDay, CBbMonth, and CBbYear is 10, what I get from that code (`dateresult`) is 1 January 2034, where it should be 11 November 2034.

Is there anything wrong in my code or I am using the wrong function?

Thank you.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger in Visual Studio and then mistakes like this, which are completely your own bad logic, will be obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you keep using the original value as the starting point. You add days to `datenow`, then you ignore that result and add months to `datenow`, then you ignore that result and add years to `datenow` and only use that last result, so of course your result only has the years added. If you were to actually use the previous result as the starting point then you would end up a final result incorporating all three operations. This:

```vb
dateresult = datenow.AddDays(CBbDay.Text)
dateresult = datenow.AddMonths(CBbMonth.Text)
dateresult = datenow.AddYears(CBbYear.Text)
```

should be this:

```vb
dateresult = datenow.AddDays(CBbDay.Text)
dateresult = dateresult.AddMonths(CBbMonth.Text)
dateresult = dateresult.AddYears(CBbYear.Text)
```

It would actually make more sense to do it in a single line of code, in which case you'd inherently use the previous result:

```vb
dateresult = datenow.AddDays(CBbDay.Text).AddMonths(CBbMonth.Text).AddYears(CBbYear.Text)
```

The following is not related to the issue specifically but I wanted to provide code so a comment doesn't really cut it. You really need to stop playing so fast and loose with data types. Don't store dates and/or times as `Strings`. .NET has dedicated data types for them for a reason. I would hope that you wouldn't convert numbers to `Strings` and then try to do arithmetic on them, but anything is possible.

You should start by turning `Option Strict On` in the project properties. That will flag a lot of errors if what you posted is representative of your code, because it will require you to use proper data types and cast/convert between them explicitly when required. Your code should look like this:

```vb
Dim dateResult As Date

dateResult = Date.Today.AddDays(CInt(CBbDay.Text))
dateResult = dateResult.AddMonths(CInt(CBbMonth.Text))
dateResult = dateResult.AddYears(CInt(CBbYear.Text))

Label17.Text = dateResult.ToShortDateString()
```

`Date.Today` will give you a `Date` value containing today's date and the time zeroed. Just use that as the starting point. No need to use `Date.Now` and remove the time yourself, no need for a variable and no need to use a `String`. The `Strings` coming from the `ComboBoxes` are converted to `Integer` values, which is what those methods require. As it was, you were relying on the system to do that cast/conversion for you. That will often work but there are times that it won't and you won't find out until your app crashes or, even worse, silently saves bad data. The `Date` value is only converted to a `String` at the point that you actually need a `String`, i.e. when displaying the data.

It's also pretty horrible that you have a control named `Label17`. Fancy having 17 `Labels` and not doing anything to distinguish their purpose. At least your `ComboBoxes` have meaningful names, even if they're a bit dodgy. EVERYTHING should have a descriptive name. You'll realise why when you come back to code that you wrote some time ago and have no idea what it's doing.

I should also note that you don't actually need to separate the declaration and initialisation of your variable:

```vb
Dim dateResult = Date.Today.AddDays(CInt(CBbDay.Text))

dateResult = dateResult.AddMonths(CInt(CBbMonth.Text))
dateResult = dateResult.AddYears(CInt(CBbYear.Text))

Label17.Text = dateResult.ToShortDateString()
```

If you have `Option Infer On`, which it is by default, a variable can be inferred to be the same type as its initialising expression, so `dateResult` will be inferred to be type `Date`.

Comment: Thank you. The code worked and I'll take the advice you gave.